# Cant add list view webpart through XML

Tags: 2013, office-365, xslt-list-view-web-part, list-view-web-part, onet

I'm trying to add a listview webpart to my default page of my sandboxed solution for SharePoint 2013 in Office 365.

I'm using a ONET file to define my webtemplate based on the STS template.
Among other features I've activated the publishing feature. 
In there I use a web feature with a elements file that provisions the default page.

Everyting is working well, I can even add a listview webpart to this page which shows the content of the default documents list.

However, it seems that with every other list (Tasks, Calendar,..) I try to show in a View element in my default page, prevents me from creating the site.

I tried several approaches:

Physically adding the calendar list to lists (Change list path in ONET file):

```
<View List="Lists/Calendar" 
        Name="Calendar"
        BaseViewID="0" 
        WebPartZoneID="TopLeftRow" 
        WebPartOrder="0"/>
```

Adding the calendar list without lists:

```
<View List="Calendar" 
        Name="Calendar"
        BaseViewID="0" 
        WebPartZoneID="TopLeftRow" 
        WebPartOrder="0"/>
```

With resource file:

```
<View List="$Resources:core,calendarList;" 
       BaseViewID="0" 
       WebPartZoneID="TopLeftRow" 
       WebPartOrder="0" />
```

With body xml:

```
<View List="Lists/Calendar" BaseViewID="0" WebPartZoneID="TopLeftRow" WebPartOrder="1">
    <![CDATA[<webParts>
          <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
              <metaData>
                  <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                  <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
              </metaData>
              <data>
                  <properties>
                      <property name="Title" type="string">Calendar</property>
                      <property name="DisableViewSelectorMenu" type="bool">True</property>
                      <property name="InplaceSearchEnabled" type="bool">False</property>
                      <property name="ShowToolbarWithRibbon" type="bool">False</property>
                      <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
                  </properties>
              </data>
          </webPart>
      </webParts>]]>
  </View>
```

None of these approaches seem to work. Am I doing something wrong here?

**Update**
It seems to be a timing issue. When I disable the feature that provisions the default page and enable it by hand it works using this:

```
<View BaseViewID="2" List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,calendar_Folder;" WebPartZoneID="TopRightRow" DefaultView="TRUE" Type="CALENDAR" WebPartOrder="1" >
    <![CDATA[ 
      <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2"> 
      <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>          
      <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart</TypeName> 
      <Title>Calendar</Title>                          
      </WebPart>]]>
  </View>
```

Any Idea how I can fix this, regarding the use of a webtemplate in a sandbox solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create the list you are trying to reference in the feature receiver that you added to your `onet.xml` file.  Then create the list view web part as you have done in your `onet.xml`.

This will result in your list being there when you are trying to reference it by creating the list view web part.